# How to call a batch file with input parameters using python script

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I want to run a batch file with input parameters using python script.

below is my code where I am calling .bat file with arg1 in python script. But the code is not working as expected, help me on how to pass input arguments

```
command =["C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\download.bat", arg1]
subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: `command = "C:\\...\\download.bat"` and `subprocess.call(command, arg1)`?

Comment: its giving error TypeError: bufsize must be an integer if I pass arg in subprocess.call